# Why string literals are allowed to be assigned to pointer of type char * in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, compiler-errors

Using visual studio, I declared a pointer of type `char *` and assigned to it a string literal. I then hovered the mouse over the string literal and it displayed its type: `(const char [4])"abc"`.

How is this allowed? it compiles without warnings or errors, whilst assigning to the pointer an array of type `const char []` fails, for obvious reasons, with an error message:

> a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"

So, why is it allowed for string literals?

```
int main(void)
{
    char *p = "abc"; // no error here
    const char str[] = "abc";
    //p = str; This line generates an error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which bit of the error message don't you understand? A `const char *` is not the same thing as a `char *`.

Comment: _and assigned it to a string literal._ no, you assigned to it.

Comment: You are not assigning a pointer to char to a string literal.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @bob am using VS 2017.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The OP is asking why VS compiles that code **without** raising a warning nor that error

Comment: I'm not familiar with that IDE, but can you specify a specific standard (e.g. C++11) as a target or at least generate more warnings?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: answer updated to incorporate info from Story Teller's comment.

In the olden days, `const` didn't exist, and people wrote things like `char* p = "abc"` all the time.  As long as the didn't then do something like `p[0] = 'z'`, their program worked.  To remain compatible with such code, some compilers allow string literals to be assigned to non-const pointers if you don't ask the compiler to be super-strict.  If you take advantage of this feature, you still should not ACTUALLY modify the string.

Comment: Um, no. String literals are const. The type of `"abc"` is `const char[4]`, as the question says.

Comment: Story Teller: no fair removing your comment when I'm trying to cite you! :)